# Runtime Error 1004: Group Excel list by indent level with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, grouping, indentation

I'm currently trying to fix an Excel VBA macro. The final goal is to group the list by indent level.

The structure is similar to this:

> Row 1....Row2..Row3
>
> Einheit-----A        -40
>
> Einheit------B       -20
>
> Einheit------C       -20
>
> Einheit------D          0

The weird thing is that the macro seems to work until row 409. In row 410 I get the run-time-error 1004. The Indent-level in line 410 is 9. Maybe you guys have an idea.

+++ Okay so I found out that the Runtime error is somehow coherent with the indent-Level. It allways appears after a row with indent level 9. +++

```
Sub AutoGroupBOM()
    'Define Variables
    Dim StartCell As Range 'This defines the highest level of assembly, usually 1, and must be the top leftmost cell of concern for outlining, its our starting point for grouping'
    Dim StartRow As Integer 'This defines the starting row to beging grouping, based on the row we define from StartCell'
    Dim LevelCol As Integer 'This is the column that defines the assembly level we're basing our grouping on'
    Dim LastRow As Integer 'This is the last row in the sheet that contains information we're grouping'
    Dim CurrentLevel As Integer 'iterative counter'
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off screen updating while running.

    'Prompts user to select the starting row. It MUST be the highest level of assembly and also the top left cell of the range you want to group/outline"
    Set StartCell = Application.InputBox("Select top left cell for highest assembly level", Type:=8)
    StartRow = StartCell.Row
    LevelCol = StartCell.Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Remove any pre-existing outlining on worksheet, or you're gonna have 99 problems and an outline ain't 1
    Cells.ClearOutline

    'Walk down the bom lines and group items until you reach the end of populated cells in the assembly level column
    For i = StartRow To LastRow

        Rows(i).Select
        Level = Cells(i, LevelCol).IndentLevel
        For j = 1 To Level - 1
            Selection.Rows.Group
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns on screen updating when done.

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found out what the problem was.

The max. grouping level in Excel is 8, so as soon as I tried to group a ninth time (indent level 9) I got the run time error!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GroupByIndent()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A6:A880")

    For Each cell In rng

        cell.Select

        For i = 1 To cell.IndentLevel

            Selection.Rows.Group

        Next

    Next cell

End Sub
```